# Prove or disprove $\lVert \vec{x}_1 + \ ... \ + \vec{x}_n \rVert ^2 = \lVert \vec{x}_1 \rVert ^2 + \ ... \ + \lVert \vec{x}_n \rVert ^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Assume that $x_i$ is orthonormal to each other.

On first glance, this looks very similar to the pythagorean theorem:

\begin{align}
\lVert \vec{x}_1 + \vec{x}_2 \rVert ^2 = \lVert \vec{x}_1 \rVert ^2 + \lVert \vec{x}_2 \rVert ^2 \iff \vec{x}_1 \cdot \vec{x}_2 = 0
\end{align}

However, it doesn't feel correct since I suspect that pythagorean theorem would apply only to a triangle. Can I get some pointers on how to proceed?

Comment: The two-variable case **is** about a triangle. (Or is that just what you meant to say?)

Comment: For more than two variables, we have a sequence of triangles. You can use proof by induction.

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant. I got it now. Thanks.

Comment: It was hard for me to realize that a sequence of triangles can be written like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

Upon expansion,

$$\left\| \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right\|^2=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n \langle x_i, x_j\rangle $$

Now, use the property given to you to proceed.